# Word meaning "unskippable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I searched on Thesaurus but found [nothing](http://thesaurus.com/browse/unskippable).

I want to use it in a sentence like the following:

> Tuning his guitar was his [...] nightly ritual.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you could skip *it* if *it* wasn't a **ritual**.

Comment: how about `obligratory`

Comment: @qarma That should make an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider **inviolable**: *too important to be ignored or treated with disrespect.*

> Tuning his guitar was his inviolable nightly ritual.

Answer (score 4):

To the extent `unskippable` means roughly "consistently obeyed" I think any of the following would suffice:

> Routine, unvarying, established, standard.

Note though that "unskippable" doesn't seem the right word to me since the guitarist *could* skip tuning, though he/she does not. He is able to skip, but doesn't. If you truly mean he is incapable of skipping, then consider:

> mandatory, required, compulsory.

Answer (score 3):

Consider "[**inevitable**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Inevitable)," "[**unavoidable**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unavoidable)" and "[**inescapable**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Inescapable)."

> *I look over to the hands that count down to my [**unavoidable nightly ritual**](https://thenewcurrent.jux.com/866691)*.
>
> *In the past few months this has become an [**inescapable nightly ritual**](http://bmancilla.com/2012/05/) for me*.

"[**sacrosanct**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sacrosanct)" might work too.

> "*These officials had air of audaciously disturbing his [**sacrosanct daily routine**](http://www.anoopdixith.com/puzz/defective-watch/) for centuries...*"

Answer (score 2):

How about **[unmissable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unmissable)**?

> So good that it should not be missed:

But isn't it redundant to describe a "nightly ritual" as unskippable?

Answer (score 0):

**[fixed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fixed)**

> not fluctuating; always at the same time: *a fixed holiday.*

*Most artists have a **fixed ritual** or routine that they rely on to inspire their efforts from concept to fruition.* [~](http://thefunstar.com/artists/mike-gordon/)

---

**[indispensable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indispensable)** would be a stronger adjective also

> (of duties, rules etc.) Unbendable, that cannot be set aside or ignored.

*As the hour grows later, food takes on greater weight: an **indispensable ritual** in preparation for the abyss of night, an important sense of satiation at day's end.* [~](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/11/24/magazine/food-sweet-dreams.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found the word used twice, and spelled differently but I believe the metaplasm is a critic's play on the author's style:

> To say that Mr Curtis's introduction and running comment are in their
>   way as delightful, as “**unskipable**" as the letters themselves, is to
>   do them only exact justice. -The Critic; an illustrated monthly review of literature, ... v.14 1889

&

> They should be seen as they appeared, in the midst of much advertising
>   of the ordinary sort, where they stood out with an enticing boldness
>   that made them **unskippable**.-American printer and lithographer.
>   v.31 1900-1901 Sep-Feb.

Despite the hapax legomenon nature, the use by an American printer baptizes the word's legitimacy.